# Conflict using flutter_icons_launcher with flutter_icons packages

Tags: android, ios, flutter, visual-studio-code, flutter-dependencies

I wanted to change my app's Launcher Icon using the [flutter icons launcher](https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_launcher_icons) package like

```
dev_dependencies:
  flutter_launcher_icons: "^0.7.3"

flutter_icons:
  android: "launcher_icon"
  ios: true
  image_path: "assets/icon/icon.png"
```

But then i get an error of conflicting package definitions for "**flutter_icons:**" since the package [flutter icons](https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_icons) uses `flutter_icons:` definition too as follow

```
dependencies:
  flutter_icons: ^1.1.0
```

Is there a way of using the 2 packages in the same project?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Move your second flutter_icons: one space back and you're good to go.

In your code, you are doing like this

```
dev_dependencies:
  flutter_test:
    sdk: flutter
  flutter_launcher_icons: ^0.9.0

  flutter_icons:
  android: "launcher_icon"
  ios: true
  image_path: "assets/logo.png"
```

You should do it like this

```
dev_dependencies:
  flutter_test:
    sdk: flutter
  flutter_launcher_icons: ^0.9.0

flutter_icons:
  android: "launcher_icon"
  ios: true
  image_path: "assets/logo.png"
```

Note: In the above question, you write it exactly fine but in your real code you write it wrong.